# To resolve different strategy at compile time by template parameter "T"'s size

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to implement a naive GC system for learning purpose. Basically, it will provide an interface of `newElement` for users to "new" an object.

The strategy that i want to resolve is to allocate the object by different strategy(a pool for small object/malloc for big...) according to the object type, for example:

```
T* newElement(Args&&... args)
{
    if(sizeof(T) < 4){
        // strategy1
        return newImpl1(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else if(4 <= sizeof(T) < 16){
        // strategy2
        return newImpl2(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } else{
        // strategy3
        return newImpl3(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

i think this cost can be at compile time but not run time, since the `sizeof(T)` can be evaluate at compile time. I know in C++17, we have features like `constexpr if` to deal with this kind of situations. However, i am dealing with VS 2015, it only support C++11 and C++14. So, i consider the process as two different phases:

1. the "new" should accept different kind of label (by type) to resolve the different strategy
2. the "dispatch" should accept T as input and has a way to output the proper label(by type)

Generally, the aim of phase 2 is to output different kinds of label(no matter values or types) by a series of conditional expressions.

There are two kinds of solutions come to my mind.

```
enum class Strategy {
    small, middle, big
};

constexpr size_t SmallMiddleThreshold = 4;
constexpr size_t MiddleBigThreshold = 8;

template
<Strategy s=Strategy::small>
struct newImpl {
    template
    <typename T, typename... Args>
    static T* apply(Args&&... args)
    {
        cout << "small!" << endl;
        return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template
<>
struct newImpl<Strategy::middle> {
    template
    <typename T, typename... Args>
    static T* apply(Args&&... args)
    {
        cout << "middle!" << endl;
        return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template
<>
struct newImpl<Strategy::big> {
    template
    <typename T, typename... Args>
    static T* apply(Args&&... args)
    {
        cout << "big!" << endl;
        return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

#### Solution 1

use the variadic templates to expand the conditionals.

```
template
<bool Condition1=true, bool... Conditions>
struct SizeDispatcher1 {
    constexpr static Strategy value = Strategy::small;
};

template
<bool... Conditions>
struct SizeDispatcher1<false, Conditions...> {
    constexpr static Strategy value = SizeDispatcher2<Conditions...>::value;
};

template
<bool Condition2 = true, bool... Conditions>
struct SizeDispatcher2 {
    constexpr static Strategy value = Strategy::middle;
};

template
<bool... Conditions>
struct SizeDispatcher2<false, Conditions...> {
    constexpr static Strategy value = SizeDispatcher3<Conditions...>::value;
};

template
<bool Condition3 = true, bool... Conditions>
struct SizeDispatcher3 {
    constexpr static Strategy value = Strategy::big;
};

template
<typename T>
struct SizeDispatcher {
    constexpr static Strategy value = 
        SizeDispatcher1< 
            sizeof(T) < SmallMiddleThreshold,
            SmallMiddleThreshold <= sizeof(T) && sizeof(T) < MiddleBigThreshold,
            MiddleBigThreshold <= sizeof(T)
        >::value;
};

template
<typename T, typename... Args>
T* newElement(Args&&... args)
{
    return newImpl<SizeDispatcher<T>::value>::apply<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

#### Solution 2

use partial specialization to match the different cases.

```
template
<bool Condition1=true, bool Condition2=false, bool Condition3=false>
struct SizeDispatcherImpl {
    constexpr static Strategy value = Strategy::small;
};

template
<>
struct SizeDispatcherImpl<false, true, false> {
    constexpr static Strategy value = Strategy::middle;
};

template
<>
struct SizeDispatcherImpl<false, false, true> {
    constexpr static Strategy value = Strategy::big;
};

template
<typename T>
struct SizeDispatcher {
    constexpr static Strategy value = 
        SizeDispatcherImpl< 
            sizeof(T) < SmallMiddleThreshold,
            SmallMiddleThreshold <= sizeof(T) && sizeof(T) < MiddleBigThreshold,
            MiddleBigThreshold <= sizeof(T)
        >::value;
};
```

---

However, i have some questions about the above code.

First, can it correctly fulfill my requirement? That is, to resolve the different strategy at compile time?

Second, both of the solutions have at least these following drawbacks: 1. the "Dispatcher" are tight coupling with the conditional expressions(format, sequences...), which is definitely not a good practice of coding. 2. have not clear semantics.

So, how to solve the question properly and better if possible?(To produce different label by a series of conditional expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those solutions do seem a bit complicated.  Another solution would be to use overloaded helper functions, or maybe even overload `newElement` itself, with SFINAE restrictions.  One benefit is that the condition can be seen right next to the implementation.

```
 #include <type_traits>
 #include <iostream>

 template <typename T, typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) < 4)>* = nullptr>
 T* newElement(Args&& ... args) {
     std::cout << "small!" << std::endl;
     return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }

 template <typename T, typename... Args,
     std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) >= 4 && sizeof(T) < 16)>* = nullptr>
 T* newElement(Args&& ... args) {
     std::cout << "middle!" << std::endl;
     return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }

 template <typename T, typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(T) >= 16)>* = nullptr>
 T* newElement(Args&& ... args) {
     std::cout << "big!" << std::endl;
     return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }
```

Comment: Are these three function have the same signatures(same parameter type and list and same function name), or they don't(different template parameter)?

Comment: Template parameters are part of the signature of a function template. So these count as three different function templates.

Comment: Why the format like ```template <typename T, enable_if_t<bool exp about T>, typename... Args>``` cannot work, with a hint of "cannot deduce the template parameter" for ```_formal```?

Comment: You have `enable_if_t<expression>` alone as a template parameter? Assuming the expression is true, that would evaluate to an unnamed parameter of type `void`, and `void` is not a valid type for a template parameter.  That's why I added `* = nullptr`, to make it a `void*` template parameter with default template argument.

Comment: why the default argument is necessary?

Comment: You don't want to need to type `newElement<T, nullptr>()` where the `nullptr` doesn't even mean anything.

Comment: I mean why cannot just ```enable_if_t<expression>*```, why the default argument is required?

Comment: The template parameter needs to get its value from somewhere. So if there's no default argument, you would have to provide it as in `newElement<T, nullptr>()` rather than just `newElement<T>()`. Another option would be `typename = std::enable_if_t<expression>`.